# Local Network Share

Tags: 14.04

How could I solve this error??[image: Local Network Share] when I am trying to share my folder to Local network.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that limits for open files. Try to use following command:

```
ulimit -n 16384
```

if it works make it permanent by adding:

`*               -       nofile          16385`

in /etc/security/limits.conf